# jquery ui-autocomplete-loading class gets added but styles don't apply

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Im using jquery ui autocomplete for a search on my site. I want to add in a simple loading spinner while returning results. jquery ui automatically adds in the class 'ui-autocomplete-loading' when results are being loaded. I've added some css to this class to add in a background image when it's active. The strange thing is, the class gets added and removed perfectly fine but the styles aren't applied. However, if I add the ui-autocomplete-loading class manually, the styles show up. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out!

Automatically added 'ui-autocomplete-loading'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyLNj.jpg

Manually added 'ui-autocomplete-loading'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BReHS.png

The CSS:

```
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
  background: red url('/static/images/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat right center!important;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding the class automatically versus manually?

Comment: automatically means jquery ui is adding the class when search results are loading. Manually is when I add the class to the input myself.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the jQuery UI script you will see that the `.ui-autocomplete-loading` class is automatically applied.  This style can be overridden in your css to display the image or styling of your choice.

One of the catches is a possible CSS conflict with your other styles.  You can find out if this is a problem by debugging the scripts in DevTools, Firebug, etc. and then inspecting the element styles as they are applied.

The easy fix is to increase the specificity of the class.  For example, adding the `input` element in your CSS may do the trick. `input.ui-autocomplete-loading { background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat right center; }`

You can see in the example below, I inspected the CSS rules and found that the style from the Foundation framework was overriding my `.ui-autocomplete-loading` style.  I was able to verify that by unchecking the style while debugging the script.

[image]

So, I modified my CSS and you can see the updated styles here.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit difficult here because you are trying to override the existing background.

What you can do is add a button in the input field. Then you can add your styling for the autocomplete loading. Just use a negative margin to position the icon.

e.g.

```
<input><button class="search_icon"><button></input>

.search_icon 
{
    margin-left: -20px;
    background: #fff url(/assets/images/search-icon.png) no-repeat;
    border-style: none;
    width: 15px;
}

.ui-autocomplete-loading
{
   background: #fff url(/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat 95%;  
}
```

Comment: When I download jquery-ui I don't get assets/images directory in the source.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that is used by jquery-ui itself on their website at 
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote.

Make sure images directory contains 'ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif'.

```
<style>

       .ui-autocomplete-loading {

       background: white url("/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;

       }

</style>
```